# Communication between arduino and RasPi3

Tags: i2c

I am new to RasPi, I need help on how to have arduino communicate with Pi. So basically I want arduino to send message("TAKE A PICTURE") to Pi3. On receiving the message the Pi3 should take Picture using a noircam. The communication could be either though GPIO pins or USB connection. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It depend on what your programming skills are. I'll go with python and [pyserial](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) and [picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/). It'll work both for usb and gpio serial.

Basic code will be create a python script that start at reboot using crontab. That script will wait for a serial input from the serial port and read whatever comes. If the message is "TAKE A PICTURE" then, run code to take a picture using picamera.

In arduino, you'll need to create a sketch that send the message at certain event. It could be time based, user input, or sensor input.

You can get rid of the arduino anyways and handle everything from the pi. If you want to take the picture when some event happend, like reading from a sensor is a certain value, you can read those from the pi itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My project is actually about visible light communication; How it works

Use arduino UNo as a transmitter and another arduino Uno as a receiver
When the light communication between transmitter and receiver is disturbed a buzzer will go off.
Then the arduino on the receiving end sends a message to pi to take a a picture of whatever is causing the visible light communication disturbance

Comment: Thanks for your response. My project is actually about visible light communication;

 How it works

Use arduino UNo as a transmitter and another arduino Uno as a receiver

When the light communication between transmitter and receiver is disturbed a buzzer will go off.

Then the arduino on the receiving end sends a message to pi to take a a picture of whatever is causing the visible light communication disturbance

I am done with the code for the visible light communication between the two arduinos and the codes of sending from arduino to Pi, my only problem is putting them together

Comment: In that case, the easiest way to do it's that the receiver is the pi itself, or use a serial interface to talk from the Arduino receiver to the pi. In the pi, read the serial (ie using python and pyserial) and then use picamera to take the picture.

Comment: alright. The part where you say I can use a pi as a receiver intrigues me. Can you please share side where I can learn to do that please.

Comment: What are you using for receiving the light? If you're using an analog sensor, you'll need a ADC (analog to digital converter) since the pi doesn't have an on board ADC (only digital). The way that I'd do it, is with a python script that mimics the arduino receiver data and then add the camera stuff.

Comment: I'm using a phototransistor to sense the light.

Also, may you please advice me or guide me as to how to mimic arduino on a python script please. A site could be useful also

Comment: Here is a image that shows something like that you want to do https://i.stack.imgur.com/10hGI.png Also, To work with the pi and python, take a look at this: https://makezine.com/projects/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-and-python/

Comment: Thanks. The circuit diagram isnt my issue. My issue and challenge is writing a python code that can detect light using the phototransistor and raspberryPi

Comment: Take a look at the second link (https://makezine.com/projects/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-and-python/) that I sent to you. Follow that tutorial and you'll get basic knowledge on how to do it. Then, you can start digging in.